# Unable to mine smart contract using Oraclize - Invalid JSON RPC response,error code : -32603

Tags: private-blockchain, oracles

I am trying to use Oraclize to make a REST call. Please find below my contract code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
import "./usingOraclize.sol";  //Importing Oraclize(verion 0.4)
contract TestOraclizeCall is usingOraclize {
     uint public price;
     event Log(string text);
     event LogOracleConnection(OraclizeAddrResolverI obj);
     OraclizeAddrResolverI OAR;

 //Constructor
 function TestOraclizeCall() {
     OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x6f485c8bf6fc43ea212e93bbf8ce046c7f1cb475);   // address of the resolver     
     emit LogOracleConnection(OAR);
    // update();
 }

 function checkOARInstance() public view returns(address){
     OAR.getAddress();//returns no address
 }
 function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) public {
      if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();
      emit Log(_result);
      //price = parseInt(_result, 2);
   }
 function update()public{
    oraclize_query("URL","json(http://**/storage/compartments/list?next_page=).Data");
 }
 }
```

However when I try to execute the update() method the call to mining process fails :

> Invalid JSON RPC response,error code : -32603.

The ethereum bridge has been successfully deployed on a private blockchain and both address resolver and connector contracts have deployed and generated the contract address, but still I am not able to execute any oraclize methods.

Blockchain running on Ubuntu machine.

Request any help on this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like problems with Web3 API implementation on client side.  Where are you calling `update()` method from?  I mean geth console, Mist, MyEtherWallet, or, maybe, your own UI code?

Answer (score 0):

Try an earlier version of Truffle, some users have reported issues, arising from the new Solc used there. Reverting to Truffle v4.1.3 has generally gotten things for working for others.